# How to take Postal Code Checker using Regular expression and Input in Python 3

Tags: regex, python-3.x, validation, if-statement, input

My code *should allow user's input to match the Regular expression of my "**postal code**"* and **print** out Match found - Valid postal code.
I need help to get my result, but i keep getting TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object.

```
import re

print("--- POSTAL CODE CHECKER PROGRAM --- ")
# user_input_1 = input('Please enter the city/province: ')
user_input_2 = input('Please enter the postal code: ')

postalCode = ["T, V, R, E, A, X, B, K, L, M, N ,P, C , G, H, J, S, Y, 0-9"]

pattern = re.compile(r'[TVREAXBKLMNPCGHJSY]\d[TVREAXBKLMNPCGHJSY] \d[TVREAXBKLMNPCGHJSY]\d')

if user_input_2 == pattern.match(postalCode):
    print('Match found - Valid postal code:{}'.format(user_input_2))
else:
    print("Error - No match found")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `re.match` returns a match object, not a string. Use `if pattern.fullmatch(user_input_2)`:

```
import re

print("--- POSTAL CODE CHECKER PROGRAM --- ")
# user_input_1 = input('Please enter the city/province: ')
user_input_2 = input('Please enter the postal code: ')

pattern = re.compile(r'[TVREAXBKLMNPCGHJSY]\d[TVREAXBKLMNPCGHJSY] \d[TVREAXBKLMNPCGHJSY]\d')

if pattern.fullmatch(user_input_2):
    print('Match found - Valid postal code:{}'.format(user_input_2))
else:
    print("Error - No match found")
```

See the [Python 3 demo](http://rextester.com/MBOSO90169)

The `postalCode = ["T, V, R, E, A, X, B, K, L, M, N ,P, C , G, H, J, S, Y, 0-9"]` line seems redundant here.

Note that [`re.fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) (available in Python 3 `re`) requires the whole string to match the pattern. In Python 2, you would need to add `$` at the end of your regex and use `if pattern.match(user_input_2)`.

Comment: Thanks i also have another question @Wiktor, What if i want the error to be **printed** as _Error - No Postal codes starts with D. Please try again._

Comment: If you have a cycle, add a flag and set it true if there was at least one match. Then display the notification if the flag is false.

Comment: Sorry please give me a sample, am new to python @Wiktor. Thanks.